# XML and XSLT results separated with commas

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using the xslt language to transform an xml document. The result that I am getting at the moment is not exactly what I want to achieve. I want to be able to get an xml format result separated with commas.
I want my result to be in this correct way with returned values separated with commas.

```
<caller>1013, Product Enquiry, Courrier, Mobile Phone, Undecided</caller>
```

But what I am getting at the moment is wrong and it is this one below.
1013Product EnquiryCourrierMobile PhoneUndecided

This is my caller.xml file.

```
<caller>
    <number message="id">1013</number>
    <number message="voice">Product Enquiry</number>
    <number message="delivery">Courrier</number>
    <number message="device">Mobile Phone</number>
    <number message="subscription">Undecided</number>
</caller>
```

This is my xslt caller.xsl file.

````
<xsl:template match="/" priority="0">
    <xsl:if test="position()>2">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <caller>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="caller/number">              
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </caller>    
</xsl:template>```
````

I am getting two results with this xslt code and none of them has commas in it.
I will appreciate if some can point me int he right direction to fix it.

Comment: Well, there is e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="caller/number" separator=", "/>` in XSLT 2 and later (supported on most platform using Saxon (Saxon HE exists in an open source version for Java, .NET, C/C++/Python, SaxonJS fills the gap for Node.js and the browser)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you want can be produced quite easily using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/caller">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="number">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if your processor supports it:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/caller">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="number" separator=", "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. It works magic with XSLT 2.0 using Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7. Once again, thank you.

Comment: If the answer suits you, it's important to click the "check" icon.  This way, the question comes up as "answered" in stackoverflow.  Also, it gives more points to the person who contributed the accepted response.

Comment: I have a question that is not exactly what I asked before. If I do not want to have a comma right after the first element, is there a logical way to achieve that? I mean to get a result that is displaying like this one? <caller>1013 Product Enquiry, Courrier, Mobile Phone, Undecided</caller> That is, no comma between the first two elements. I mean no comma between 1013 and Product Enquiry.

Comment: I have tried this approach, but the result is the same as the previous one. Is there a way that I can improve it to achieve the desired result? ```    <xsl:template match="/"> 
        <caller>
        <xsl:for-each select="caller/number">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position()=1"/>
                <xsl:when test="position()=last()">, </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>, </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </caller>
    </xsl:template>```

Comment: You could do, for example, (in the XSLT 2.0 version) `<xsl:value-of select="string-join(number[position() le 2], ' '), number[position() ge 3]" separator=", "/>`.

Comment: Or even simpler: `<xsl:value-of select="number[1], string-join(number[position() gt 1], ', ')" />`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it to work with the XSLT 2.0 version above that you suggested. I really very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your question answered now?

Comment: Yes, it is answered. I could not find the "check" icon you asked me to click.

Comment: Oh, great. I have done it now. I have also learnt something new today with this. Thanks.

Comment: *I have also learnt something new today with this."* That's the important thing here, for all of us.